# How to get first a href tag from every div using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup's elements class to get the links in the < a href > tag within a specific div. In most cases, the div has only one < a href > tag. However, there is one such scenario where there are two < a href > tags in the div. In such scenarios, I want to get only the first < a href > tag URL and ignore the second one. Is there any way to achieve this? Please help.

**Java Code**

```
String response =  ; // html code
Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);
if (document != null) {
 Elements links = document.select("div.kCrYT > a[href]"); // gets all the URL's
 for (Element link : links) {
   String linkHref = link.attr("href");
   System.out.println("linkHref: " + linkHref);
 }
```

**HTML code**

```
<div>
    <div class="ZINbbc xpd O9g5cc uUPGi">
        <div class="kCrYT">
            <a href="/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjvy9fH9unoAhWLmOAKHZMGCYcQFjAaegQIARAB&amp;usg=AOvVaw3g3Lc1rBf-L5ZlWeE9ggx7">
                <div class="BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd">
                    Mobile phone - Wikipedia
                </div>
                <div class="BNeawe UPmit AP7Wnd">
                    https://en.wikipedia.org › wiki › Mobile_phone
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="x54gtf"></div>
        <div class="kCrYT">
            <div>
                <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">
                                A mobile phone, cellular phone, cell phone, cellphone or hand phone, sometimes shortened to simply mobile, cell or just phone, is a portable telephone that can&nbsp;...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="ZINbbc xpd O9g5cc uUPGi">
        <div class="kCrYT">
            <a href="/url?q=https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjvy9fH9unoAhWLmOAKHZMGCYcQtwIwG3oECAIQAQ&amp;usg=AOvVaw0SEels_2PKSQyaFaMbZQpT">
                <div class="BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd">
                    Mobile Phone and App News / Reviews | iOS, Android, and More ...
                </div>
                <div class="BNeawe UPmit AP7Wnd">
                    https://www.digitaltrends.com › mobile
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="x54gtf"></div>
        <div class="kCrYT">
            <a href="/url?q=https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjvy9fH9unoAhWLmOAKHZMGCYcQuAIwG3oECAIQAg&amp;usg=AOvVaw1NrWt0iIdzg2X2zgb-h8Vq">
                <div class="lcJF1d SXn0g GXKcHe p1CInd">
                    <img class="EYOsld" style="display:block;max-width:120px;max-height:90px" alt="Video for mobile" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" id="dimg_1" data-deferred="1" />
                    <div class="qW7zYd HMoqlc"></div>
                    <div class="qW7zYd X8r0X" style="background-size:36px"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div>
                <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">
                                <span class="r0bn4c rQMQod">3 days ago</span>
                                <span class="r0bn4c rQMQod"> &middot; </span>News, reviews, and discussion regarding Android, iOS, and everything else in the mobile realm ...Posted: 3 days ago
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rl7ilb"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `<a>` tags are direct children of the relevant `<div>` tag, you can use the [first-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) pseudo-selector:

```
document.select("div.kCrYT > a:first-child[href]")
```

If that is not guaranteed, you can use the [first-of-type](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp) pseudo-selector to get the equivalent effect:

```
document.select("div.kCrYT > a:first-of-type[href]")
```

### EDIT

Some more details for the above solution, in case it helps other people (I know it did not work for the OP, as noted in their comment).

The jSoup version I used was 1.13.1:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The code:

```
private void getDivs() {
    String response = testHtml; // the sample html code
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);
    if (document != null) {
        // this works:
        Elements links = document.select("div.kCrYT > a:first-child[href]"); 
        // this also works:
        //Elements links = document.select("div.kCrYT > a:first-of-type[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {
            String linkHref = link.attr("href");
            System.out.println("linkHref: " + linkHref);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much. But I get an exception when trying both the approaches. Could not parse query 'a:first-of-type[href]'

Anyway, i fixed it using this,

document.select(" div.kCrYT > a[href]:not(:has(div.lcJF1d.SXn0g.GXKcHe.p1CInd))")

Comment: OK - glad you got a solution! I added some more info to the answer, for future viewers of the question. I don't know why you got the error you were seeing.